# Get Product by Handle in Shopify Rest API

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Does Shopify API offer `getProductByHandle` ?

I feel that this is a very basic API request, when building a site of your own.
However, I wasn't able to find this endpoint, only one requiring ID, that is however missing when a user comes to `/products/my-product`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `https://XXX.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-07/products.json?handle=house`

This will retrieve the Product by handle